# Redux store of an NPM package

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

I have created a react npm package with redux store and have another react redux application. I am importing the npm package. Now I have two redux stores, one from the package and another from the importing application. I am getting an undefined error for useSelector while trying to access the component of the npm package which uses redux.
Following is the code for how I am importing two stores.

```
import store from './redux';//From main application
import { store_artifact } from '@testFeed/azureartifactfeed';//From package application

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store_artifact}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Following is the error while navigating to the component coming from the package:

*Page2.js:21  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allPersonaList')
at Page2 (Page2.js:21:1)*

Here, allPersonaList is the container that holds the value set by redux.

Editing with package.json
NPM package:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Importing application:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testFeed/azureartifactfeed": "^0.1.46",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.5.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "msal": "^1.4.17",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-avatar": "^5.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.6.0",
    "router": "^1.3.7",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Edit: 03
Have added explicit context and called the same custom selector.

```
const store1Context = React.createContext();
const store2Context = React.createContext();

root.render(
  <Provider store={store} context={store1Context}>
    <Provider store={store_artifact} context={store2Context}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </Provider>
);


export const useStore1Dispatch = createDispatchHook(store1Context);
export const useStore1Selector = createSelectorHook(store1Context);

export const useStore2Dispatch = createDispatchHook(store2Context);
export const useStore2Selector = createSelectorHook(store2Context);
```

Comment: You should share more info on your package.json. Is it setup to use workspaces? maybe you're importing different instances of React / Redux ?

Comment: @andrew- Both are different, one is a part of node modules.  The purpose of creating the node modules is to increase the reusability of the package.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain multiple redux stores, you need to give the `Provider` explicit `context` objects.
Check out the redux docs for more info: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#multiple-stores

---

Alternatively, you could change your npm package to export a root reducer (instead of the store) and then combine it with your application root reducer... this way you you should be able to get away with one single redux store (which is much easier to deal with IMO).